# Why is acceleration intuitively greatest at endpoints of simple harmonic motion?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

In simple harmonic motion (for example a spring moving horizontally), acceleration is greatest when the mass reaches either end of the spring. Using the formula $F = ma = kx$ and then $a = \frac{kx}{m}$, it makes sense that acceleration is greatest when $x$ is max.

Why does this make sense intuitively? Why is change in velocity instantaneously the greatest at the endpoints?

Comment: You seem to answer your question in your question. The force is the largest, so the acceleration is the largest. Acceleration is exactly the same thing as instantaneous rate of change of velocity. So if you understand the former you understand the latter. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think you've already made the best intuitive argument: acceleration is greatest when the force is greatest, which is when the spring is maximally compressed or stretched.

Answer (score 1):

Because the force is proportional to the displacement from the equilibrium position $F=-kx$, the further you from the equilibrium position the stronger the force and since the mass that's undergoing SHM isn't changing as well as friction being absent, the force is greatest so acceleration is highest.

Also acceleration is completely independent of instantaneous velocity.  The object isn't just sitting at the endpoints its spending as much time there as any position, which is an infinitesimal amount.

Answer (score 0):

A spring's pull or push that causes acceleration is going to be greatest when it's extended or squished the most.

Answer (score 0):

Hint v=wroot(A^2-x^2) ,that is the velocity differentiate it and put x=A you will get result.(sorry for not using math jax i am new to site).

Comment: [Time to learn](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition goes wrong because you do not correctly take into account that velocity and acceleration both have direction. This means: in 3D they are vectors, in 1D (as in your example) they have a sign. The important aspect is that their direction is independent of each other which is not intuitively clear in the first place.

To avoid confusion, let me set up the experiment precisely: the mass can move horizontally and it is attached to two springs, one on either side. In this way we get a symmetric situation with a defined zero position.

When the mass is in the zero position, no net force by the springs is acting on the mass (they cancel each other). No force means no acceleration means no change in speed. The mass moves freely without change of speed as if no springs exist.

When the mass moves, say, to the right, the springs start to produce some net force acting on the mass. This force will cause acceleration *to the left* which is changing the speed by decreasing its absolute value but not yet its direction.

The more to the right the mass gets, the stronger the force gets and the bigger is the change in speed until finally the speed gets to Zero and after that changes its direction.

All the time, the acceleration is to the left, and its maximum absolute value is at the end point where the velocity changes sign. When the mass is at the zero position again then the acceleration is zero and starts to change *its* sign.